# Import line delimited geojson to single column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, import, json

Given a large file of line delimited geojson:

```json
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "kitten_locations",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { ...
```

I would like to populate the target table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE kitten_locations (
   data jsonb
)
```

I have tried using ogr2ogr, but that splits it out into many columns. I can remove the feature collection bits and just import the objects. However, I am wondering if there is an easier way to **populate the jsonb column with the features of the feature collection**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First import your data with ogr2ogr into `mytable`
- Then, insert the features as GeoJSON objects into `kitten_locations` :

```sql
INSERT INTO kitten_locations(data)
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t)::jsonb FROM mytable t;
```

- Finally, delete the imported table (with splitted columns)

```sql
DROP mytable;
```